# Converting Cell array of function handle into a single array of function handle

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, function-handle

I need to build up a vector of non-linear equations to be used in `fsolve` to solve it. But I should make each element of the vector in each loop iteration. How can I make up such a vector? In fact, I can not use cell array. How can I convert a cell array like `{@(x) x(1)+x(2)^2; @(x) x(1)-2*(x(2))}` into an array like `@(x) [ x(1)+x(2)^2 ; x(1)-2*(x(2))]`? Because I want to use `fsolve` to solve the system of non-linear equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `func2str` to get the function definitions in string and use `str2func` to get the desired function, if `A` is the cell array containing the function handles:

```
B = strcat(regexprep(cellfun(@func2str, A, 'uni', 0), '^@\(x\)', ''), ';');
F = str2func(strcat('@(x) [', B{:}, ']'));
```

Now `F` contains the desired function handle.

Comment: +1, but note that this only works when all variable names are identical and equal to '`x`'.

Answer (score 1):

Why convert? Why not use something like

```
% Your cell array
Fs = {@(x) x(1)+x(2)^2; @(x) x(1)-2*x(2)};

% Just use cellfun
solution = fsolve(@(y) cellfun(@(x) x(y), Fs), [0 0])
```

Comment: This should work, but then `cellfun` will be called for each evaluation and it has a performance penalty.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia: true, but it comes at the benefit of being much simpler to implement and easier to modify when things change; your solution is specific to *this* particular problem, mine is more general. Also things like `@(~)` (for constants or so) are not parsed correctly.