# MATLAB - working with function handles rather than slow symbolic expressions

Tags: matlab, function, handles

the problem I am experience is one that I haven't been able to overcome.

The actual code that I am running is a bit too complicated, and so I will just reproduce the problem here in simpler terms.

```
>> syms x 
>> T_m = [[exp(x), x^2];[x,sin(x)]];
>> sum_matrix = T_m(1,1) + T_m(1,2) + T_m(2,1) + T_m(2,2);
>> main_func = matlabFunction(sum_matrix)
main_func = 

    @(x)x+exp(x)+sin(x)+x.^2

>> integrand = @(x) exp(-x) .* main_func(x);
>> Q = integral(@(x) integrand(x), 0,2*pi);

>> Q
ans =

    9.6677
```

The main issue that I am having in my *actual* code is the use of

```
>> main_func = matlabFunction(sum_matrix)
```

In this example, the line runs almost instantaneously. The functions that I am dealing with are very complex, and this line of code takes about ~45 seconds to run, which ridiculous.. especially since I'm reiterating through this code 100+ times.

I believe a solution is to work exclusively with function handles rather than symbolic expressions. I haven't been able to do this yet though, mainly because I cannot index into matrices twice (something along the lines of T_m(x)(1,1), which works for many languages but not MATLAB).

Any insight is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: any reason a regular .m file function doesn't work?

Comment: Can you add emphasis to your question? Note that matlabFunction() is a function built in MATLAB. All it does is convert symbolic expressions to function handles.

Comment: I mean, do you really need to create functions dynamically like this?

Comment: In my actual code, T_m is in a for-loop being defined by several other functions. I break apart the functions into separate variables for readability . In my situation, these functions are well-defined in quantum theory, so the dynamic functions are necessary

Comment: Why not just do `sum_matrix = sum(sum(T_m(x)));`?  Or is the actual use case much more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

One possible option would be to use a cell array of function handles, since `funcell{k1,k2}(3)` *is* valid syntax. However, using cells would also be pretty slow.

So I suggest transforming your whole symbolic array of functions to an array-valued symbolic array, and working on that. So, with your example:

```
syms x;
T_m = [[exp(x), x^2];[x,sin(x)]];
funT = matlabFunction(T_m);
%// produces @(x)reshape([exp(x),x,x.^2,sin(x)],[2,2])
```

You can use the sum of this quantity as a new anonymous function,

```
main_func = @(x) sum(sum(funT(x)));
```

which might be the same thing that [Troy Haskin suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678275/matlab-working-with-function-handles-rather-than-slow-symbolic-expressions#comment59036614_35678275).

The main reason I decided to add an answer is to also address [your other, related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679212/matlab-indexing-twice-into-an-array-through-integral). If you want to use the individual elements of the original array of functions, you should either use a cell array of handles after all (then you just have to access `funcell{k1,k2}(x)`), or if it turns out that using cells is slower than unnecessarily computing the full array, just throw away what you don't need:

```
id1 = eye(size(T_m,1)));  %// for Kronecker delta, essentially
id2 = eye(size(T_m,2)));  %// same here
T_m12 = @(x) id1(1,:)*funT(x)*id2(:,2);

%// or even better, generally
funT_m = @(x,k1,k2) id1(k1,:)*funT(x)*id2(:,k2);
```

To complete the circle: if you start from a cell array of function handles, [you can transform that to an array-valued function handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18609314/5067311), which is really ugly and messy, but should work unless your function is a very huge beast (but [in that case, all hope's lost anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33235813/5067311)).

Final note, just for the sake of completeness: [the answer to the suggested duplicate of your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3628885/5067311) shows you how you *can* assign into the return value of a function call, without using a temporary variable. The main problem with this approach is that it makes the code impossible to read by human beings, but otherwise it is as low-level as it gets in terms of efficiency. If you're desperate, you might consider this route as well (as it doesn't involve cells, symbolic math, nor an unnecessary vector-matrix-vector product):

```
funT_m = @(x,k1,k2) subsref(funT(x),struct('type','()','subs',{{k1,k2}}));
```

But bear in mind that we're still computing the full array in `x`, we're just throwing away the unnecessary parts as efficiently as possible.

Post-final note: if you eventually want to integrate every matrix element you have, you should also consider using the full array-valued function in `integral`, making use of its `'arrayvalued',true` parameter-value pair. This will make the integration become slower, but you can compute the integral of every matrix element all at once, without having to throw away any results.